# Azure Linux Monitoring OS layer Diagnostics

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

Hi Would anyone know of the best way to monitor linux in Azure, I'm looking for a solution pack that might monitor the OS layer along with the swap file, I can get the metrics from within Azure for the hardware, but more interested in the OS

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can leverage Perf table to fetch used swap space information. Below one is a basic kusto query w.r.t it.

```
Perf
| where ( ObjectName == "Memory" )
| where ( CounterName == "% Used Swap Space" )
| summarize avg(CounterValue) by Computer, bin(TimeGenerated, 30s)
```

Just FYI, I have not reproduced / tested this but in general after we add / have an swap file using 'fallocate', set linux swap area using 'mkswap' utility, enabled the swap using 'swapon' and append swapfile details in '/etc/fstab' file then we could verify the swap status either using 'swapon --show' or 'free -h' command so its kind of confirms that, this swap status is related to '% Used Swap Space' counter under 'Perf' table.

Hope this helps!